# Pandas groupby creating many different computed columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following issue: given a dataframe of information on IDs:

```
   id  items       date
0   1      3 2019-01-22
1   1      1 2018-05-01
2   1      2 2019-03-31
3   2      2 2018-12-12
4   2      1 2018-11-26
5   2      3 2018-05-16
6   3      1 2019-01-03
7   3      4 2018-11-22
8   3      3 2018-09-11
```

I want to group by 'id', but I need a variety of metrics - latest date, earliest date, total sum of items, total sum of items since start of year, etc...

I can get this individually, by performing one groupby per metric (or using agg to get two different columns) and then joining it to the first groupby - I was wondering if there was an agg-like method such that new columns are created based on 'items' and 'date'. The result would be something like:

```
    items latest date earliest_date  items_this_year
id                                                  
1       6  2019-03-31    2018-02-01                5
2       6  2018-12-12    2018-05-16                0
3       8  2019-01-03    2018-09-11                1
```

Is there a pandas function that allows us to set a function for each column or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check with `groupby` + `agg` , and for Item in 2019 , you may still need to do it separately

```
s2=df.loc[df.date.dt.year==2019].groupby('id').items.sum()
s=df.groupby('id').agg({'items':'sum','date':['max','min']})
s.columns=s.columns.map('_'.join)
s['Item_2019']=s2
s.reset_index(inplace=True)
s
Out[718]: 
   id  items_sum   date_max   date_min  Item_2019
0   1          6 2019-03-31 2018-05-01        5.0
1   2          6 2018-12-12 2018-05-16        NaN
2   3          8 2019-01-03 2018-09-11        1.0
```

Comment: Thanks! List in agg is probably what I was looking for, didn't realise that was possible